# How to keep a digital asset in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm working with the BYFN example using 3 organizations, 2 channels. One channel(c12) between Org1 and Org2, another channel (c23) between Org2 and Org3. The first chaincode is an example where I'm able to transfer value between "A" and "B". When I run the code over c12, I can see I'm able to transfer an amount from A to B. But when I query the same chaincode over c23, the initialization is kept. I understand why (different ledgers) and etc.

Now I would like to introduce the following requirement. I, as an organization, need to transfer this value only if I have the amount available.

The sequence would be:
1. I'm on org2, I have 100, and I wanna transfer 60 to org1. And everything works as expected.
2. I'm on org2, I have 40 and I'll try to transfer 50 to org3 (another ledger - channel). This should fail because I have only 40.

How can I achieve this? 
Where will the "shared state" be stored? MSP?
The same approach would work for a complex asset?

Extra information: 
- I already have read the documentation, about the assets, account model, the examples, but usually, they are focused only one channel only. Maybe I'm losing something.
- I'm not using hyperledger composer

Answer (score 0):

In fabric you have a chaincode and a ledger different for each channel. so if you want to have the business logic descripted you need to use only one channel (with 3 orgs).

You can probably use private data to make the separation you are now doing with the two channels